# Access Denied in "Temporary Internet Files" folder in Windows7

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am getting Access Denied in "Temporary Internet Files" folder in Windows 7. There's no Security tab in the properties option, which means I am unable take ownership from there. I am an administrator on the machine. Just to clarify this issue happened to Temporary Internet Files folder in the "Documents and Settings" folder.

How do I give myself full access to that folder?

Answer (score 3):

The location of the Temporary Internet Files in Windows 7 has changed. Are you sure you're looking in the right place? `Documents and Settings` is a junction point to support older software that didn't follow Windows API rules for saving user data correctly.

Have a look in `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary Internet Files` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the folder has a blue arrow on the left side of the icon, it is a junction point (aka: Folder redirection) and is not actually a folder as explained by Randolph.

.
[image]

Comment: Yeah. I thought it was a folder and then I changed permissions for that. No problem after that to access the contents, but it causes a "bug" on Windows search, because now I have more than one occurrence for the a file inside both paths when I search... :(

Answer (score 0):

If your admin account is called TONY, then Windows 7 will no let you see and edit all of the contents of 'Temporary Internet Files' - no matter how many folder option restrictions you turn off/on. You need to create a NEW admin level account, such as ANTHONY. Login as ANTHONY and then you can go to

```
c:\user\TONY\appdata\local\temp\Temporary Internet Files
```

and see everything (when proper folder options are enabled/disabled). For example you will be able to see the Content.IE5 folder, and what's inside it. Then you can delete thing as necessary. Deleting takes forever, not because of the GIGs of junk in TIF but the number of files. Even a few hundred megs can be 10,000+ different files.